# Accessing environment variables in a Swift script using GLibc

Tags: swift, ubuntu

Is it possible to access environment variables in a Swift script in linux? What I aim to accomplish is to create a little script that detects an environment variable passed to it, whose name is ALBERT_OP. So I thought of doing:

```
#! /usr/bin/swift

import Glibc

guard let out = getenv("ALBERT_OP") else { exit (0) }
print(out)
```

However, when I ran `ALBERT_OP="teste" ./albert-swift.swift`, I get :

```
0x00007fff4913817d
```

Which I think is the output of exit(0) in the previous code.

The Getenv GNU function is documented [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Environment-Access.html#Environment-Access).

- What is the proper way of accessing environment variable information in a Swift script?

Comment: The answers in the linked-to Q&A demonstrate both how to use getenv (which returns a C string), and the (easier/recommended) ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment. That should work on Linux as well. If not, please let me know.

Comment: It worked @MartinR , apologies for not finding that earlier. Thank you!